# Build jar and download from github using jenkins pipeline dsl

Tags: github, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl, pcf

I am having jenkins pipeline that could checkout github repo and builds jar file and then deploys it to PCF. Please refer pipeline script of jenkins pipeline below

```
stage('Checkout') {
   ...
}
.
.
.
stage('Build') {
steps {
    script {
        // set executable permission on gradlew
        sh 'chmod +x gradlew'
        withEnv(["JAVA_HOME=${env.JAVA_11}"]) {
            sh './gradlew build'
        }
    }
}
}
.
.
.
stage('Deploy') {
   ...
}
```

But what I need is to download jar after build without deploy

Comment: @GeroldBroser Replaced image with code

Comment: If you don't run `gradlew` with `deploy`nothing is deployed, isn`t it? Do you mean to download the JAR manually from your Jenkins server to your local machine?

Comment: @GeroldBroser Yes we are having Stages for checkout and deploy. But here I have mentioned relevant code only

Comment: You could use a [parameterized build](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/jenkins-parameterized-builds) and a [`when` directive](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) in the Deploy stage that checks an e.g. `doDeploy` parameter. What about the download?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am looking for

**Using pipeline script:**

```
post {
    always {
        archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'build/libs/**/*.jar'
    }
}
```

**Using jenkins freestyle project:**

[image]

This will archives the build artifacts (for example, distribution zip files or jar files) so that they can be downloaded later. Archived files will be accessible from the Jenkins webpage.